# php random cells inside a table

Tags: php, mysql, html, html-table

I have this code for print a multi columns table from mysql

```
$k="<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='5'><tr>"; 
$h=mysql_query("select * from news order by id desc limit 0,12");
$col=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($h)){
    $col++; 
    $k .="
    <td>
    Text here
    </td>
    "; 
    if($col==3){
        $k .="</tr><tr>";
        $col=0;    
    }  
}
$k .="</tr></table>";
echo $k;
```

I want to add a random cells inside this table like ad-sense codes and I want the ad-sense code to display once per column.

the output should be like this

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Title :$row[name]</td>
        <td>ADV Code1</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ADV Code2</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title :$row[name]</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]</td>
        <td>ADV Code3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ADV Code4</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]</td>
        <td>Title :$row[name]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can i do this?

Regards
Piny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rand(0,2) which will give you a random number between 0 and 2. Whenever there is a new row, you create a random number, like

```
$next_ad_col = rand(0,2);
```

Since you are counting the columns in $col, you can go

```
if($col == $next_ad_col) {
  // Add ad
} else {
  $k .="<td>Text here</td>";
}
```

Then, if a new row is created (as well as before the loop), you assign a new random number:

```
if($col==3){
  $next_ad_col = rand(0,2);
  ..
```

Or something like this.

Comment: your code will print more ads per row but what i need it one ad per rows.

Comment: Don't think so. Have you really tried? The idea is to create a number between 0 and 2 before each row and place the ad in that column.